# Android: ExecutorService is not starting again after shutdown

Tags: android, database, android-room, executorservice

I'm creating a static instance of `Executorservice` in a class which extends `Application`

- MyApplication Class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 4;
    public static ExecutorService databaseWriteExecutor = 
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);
}
```

There are 2 activities which use and then `shutdown()` the executorservice

1. MainActivity which is launched by user performs shutdown() in onDestroy()

```
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // Wait for all tasks to complete then shutdown
        MyApplication.databaseWriteExecutor.shutdown();
    }
```

(No problem here, i can use `MyApplication.databaseWriteExecutor` after closing and reopening app)

2. AlarmTriggerActivity: Launched by AlarmManager(App is not running this time) where user can dismiss alarm clock with a button(Stops related service and calls finish())

Same thing here... shutdown() executor service in onDestroy()
Now if I open the app again(MainActivity) and do any operation which uses executorservice the app crashes with exception

```
E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.pk.alarmclock, PID: 25354
E AndroidRuntime: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException:
  Task com.pk.alarmclock.alarm.db.AlarmRepository$4@b99c8c4 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@73e63ad[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
```

Also if I check: `if(MyApplication.databaseWriteExecutor.isShutdown())` in onCreate() on MainActivity after reopening app it returns true

I don't understand why executor service is not re initialized after being shutdown() from `AlarmTriggerActivity` but same thing works if shutdown() from MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

I found out that app process was still alive after calling finish() on `AlarmTriggerActivity`.. because of this `MyApplication` was not launched again on reopening the app and the same instance of `ExecutorService` was used (which was `shutdown()`)

As a temporary solution im not using `shutdown()` here in `AlarmTriggerActivty`
and only using it in `MainActivity` where the app is surely killed by swipe from recents / system (So a new instance of `ExecutorService` is created when `Application` is created)